# Transition menu "on click" using CSS3

Tags: css, menu, transition

What I'm trying to do is something similar to this: http://tympanus.net/Development/SelectInspiration/index2.html . I want that the opacity of the options in my code starts without delay, so it will seem that they start in the same vertical line (as the example above). Also, i need that the div BOTON works like a buttom and not the way is working in my code. Thanks for the help.

```css
a {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: "helvetica" sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
} 

.lista {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "helvetica" sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600
} 

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li.option {
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 width: 300px;
 border-bottom: 3px black solid;
 line-height: 30px;     /*line-height centra el texto verticalmente cuando coincide con el height*/
 opacity: 0;
 left: 150px;
 transition: .3s;
}

li.option:nth-child(1) {
 transition-delay: .0s;
}
li.option:nth-child(2) {
 transition-delay: .05s;
}
li.option:nth-child(3) {
 transition-delay: .1s;
}
li.option:nth-child(4) {
 transition-delay: .15s;
}
li.option:nth-child(5) {
 transition-delay: .2s;
}

.boton:active + .menu .lista .option {
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0px;
}
```

```html
 <body>
  <div id="navbar">
   <div class="boton">
    BOTON
   </div>
   <div class="menu">
    <ul class="lista">
     <li class="option">OPCION 1</li>
     <li class="option">OPCION 2</li>
     <li class="option">OPCION 3</li>
     <li class="option">OPCION 4</li>
     <li class="option">OPCION 5</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
```

The codepen here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbMQGR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to do this is using a `checkbox` and a `label` (associated together by `id` and `for`). You can hide the checkbox so no users will see it, and then use the label to allow the checkbox to be checked and unchecked when it is clicked.

So the following CSS would be added and the HTML slightly modified:

#### CSS

```
#activate-menu {
  display:none;
}

#activate-menu + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div id="navbar">
    <input type="checkbox" name="activate-menu" id="activate-menu" />
    <label for="activate-menu">BOTON</label>
    <div class="menu">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

**So the full solution would be:**

```css
a {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-family: "helvetica" sans-serif;
 font-weight: 900;
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
} 

.lista {
 font-size: 18px;
 font-family: "helvetica" sans-serif;
 font-weight: 600
} 

ul {
 list-style: none;
}

li.option {
 position: relative;
 height: 30px;
 width: 300px;
 border-bottom: 3px black solid;
 line-height: 30px;     /*line-height centra el texto verticalmente cuando coincide con el height*/
 opacity: 0;
 left: 150px;
 transition: .3s;
}

li.option:nth-child(1) {
 transition-delay: .0s;
}
li.option:nth-child(2) {
 transition-delay: .05s;
}
li.option:nth-child(3) {
 transition-delay: .1s;
}
li.option:nth-child(4) {
 transition-delay: .15s;
}
li.option:nth-child(5) {
 transition-delay: .2s;
}

#activate-menu {
  display:none;
}

#activate-menu + label {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#activate-menu:checked ~ .menu .lista .option {
 opacity: 1;
 left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <input type="checkbox" name="activate-menu" id="activate-menu" />
  <label for="activate-menu">BOTON</label>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul class="lista">
   <li class="option">OPCION 1</li>
   <li class="option">OPCION 2</li>
   <li class="option">OPCION 3</li>
   <li class="option">OPCION 4</li>
   <li class="option">OPCION 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my problem with the button. Now my only problem is with the transition opacity. As I said, i want to synchronize the opacity but not the movement to the left, so the options would start from the same (imaginary) vertical line, as you can see in the example above. I dont know if i'm not explaining my self very well, but you can see the diference between my code and the example in the link.